# Sign in with Apple "reduced" view after already signed in

Tags: ios, swift, sign-in-with-apple

I took a look at few apps which use Sign in with Apple and noticed when user makes sign in for the first time, they show the "view" with name and email (share/hide):

[image]

And after I Sign in with Apple and delete the app and install it again from App Store, it will show a "reduced" view with just a *continue* button:

[image]

I have been following this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/4875322-sign-in-with-apple-using-swiftui and what I get after unistalling the app and installing again is the "big" view with name and email. Any idea how to show the "reduced" view if user already signed in the past ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

(after problem resolved in comments below)

**The simulator does not always work properly - use actual (*physical*) device running iOS 13 or later.**

---

*Sorry for asking in answer - don't have enough reputation to comment on your question.*

Is your sign-in (via Sign in with Apple) into app successful (can you read a name and email of the user)? If not, you should investigate why is the sign-in process failing and fix it.

It's a choise of operating system (OS) which view will appear ("big" or "reduced"). You cannot force OS to show the one you want ("big" or "reduced").

### Expected behavior

Your observation of apps from AppStore is correct -
the "big" view will appear only at first sign-in into Your App. Next sign-in in same App will be done via "reduced" view, unless you revoke the access to AppleID for that App (on your device go to *Settings* -> *Your Apple ID Name* -> *Password & Security* -> *Apps using Apple ID* -> *Your App name* -> *Stop using Apple ID*).

### Your behavior

So the behaviour - you're seeing again and again (after reinstalling app) a "big" view is indeed unexpected.

### Check-list

As first step I would recommend you to look into (your device's) Settings for the list of *Apps using your Apple ID* (see path into Settings above):

1. Is your App there after you *sign-in* with Apple into App?
2. Is your App there after you *delete* your App from device?
3. Is your App there after you *reinstal* your App?

### Check-list evaluation

If your App is not listed there at stage 1) than the sign-in is most likely not successful and you should investigate it.

If your App is listed there at all stages (1 - 3) I would just revoke the permission&restart, delete an app and restart the device.

Comment: I can read name and email. And regarding your checklist: 3x yes. Revoking permissions, restarting etc. did not change anything. Actually even if I successully sign in (checked with debugger - it lands on  self.signInSucceeded(true)) and press the button again without unisntalling the app, it shows the "big" view. Maybe you find some time to take a short look at the code ? The whole finished project is available to download on the website I mentioned

Comment: ok, that's weird. I've downloaded and build&run the final project on my *physical* device. I can see the "big" screen only on first sign-in. On repeted sign-in and also after deleting app and reinstalling back I see only the "reduced" view. After revoking permission (stop using Apple ID for that app) the "big" screen appears. So everything as expected at my device. I've tested on real iPhone XR, iOS 14.2, protected by FaceID. I'm using Apple Developer Program team account for signing app. What's your device? Do you also run the final project?

Comment: running on the physical device solved the problem ! I previously tested on iOS 13 Simulator, now tried on the real iPhone and it works as expected. Thanks a lot for taking the effort !

Comment: thank you for your message, I'm happy it's working now! I've updated the answer with this working solution.